# =IF(VLOOKUP(...)...) formula returning error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to write a formula to return a `Y` or `N` after it looks something up.

The formula I have is: `=IF(VLOOKUP(B6,HIRES!A:A,1,FALSE)>"","Y","N")`

I need it to return `Y` if it finds the value in the lookup and if it does not find the value, I would like it to return `N`.

Could someone please help me fix my formula?

Comment: Try changing `>""` to `>0`

Comment: Or `>""` to `<>""`.

Answer (score 4):

When `VLOOKUP` fails to find something, it returns a `#N/A` error, so your condition should check for this.

Try this instead:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,HIRES!A:A,1,FALSE)),"N","Y")
```

The `ISERROR` function returns `TRUE` when `VLOOKUP` yields and error, and `FALSE` otherwise. So, you have to reverse the order of the `Y` and `N` arguments in your `IF` function.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, just for the record...

```
=IFERROR(T(MATCH(B6,HIRES!A:A,0))&"Y","N")
```

`IFERROR` returns value of formula in the first argument, if such formula leads to an error, second argument value is returned. `MATCH` can be used instead of `VLOOKUP` in this particular case. `T` returns an empty string if its argument is not text. `&` concatenates such empty string (as `MATCH` returns either an integer or error) to `Y`.